# Angular/ngrx application breaks on logout click

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have been trying to solve this for 4-5 days, but still can't find the cause of the problem.

As title says, every time I click logout button application browser freezes, can't close the tab, in order to run the app again I have to open another one or close the browser via Task Manager.

I assume the problem is with the `ngrx/effect`, I'm using it to clear the `localstorage`.

Here is it:

```js
@Effect() logout$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(fromActions.LOGOUT)
        .pipe(
            tap((action: fromActions.Logout) => {
                return this.authService.logout();
            }))
```

Here is the method:

```js
logout() {
    localStorage.clear();
  }
```

And also the token is still there, the action is not dispatched, I checked the action, no type errors..

Here are two photos, before logout clicked and after:
[image: Not clicked]
[image: Logout clicked]

EDIT: 
Action dispatch:

```js
onLogout() {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromActions.Logout());
  }
```

Reducer:

```js
case AuthActions.LOGOUT: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                loggedIn: false
            }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the reducers code and the dispatch call?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I even don't need reducer code because it's set based on localStorage, if there is a token I set it to `loggedIn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your effect you are returning the Logout action, infinite loop.

Try creating a LogoutSuccess action and return it when Logout succeed.

```
... .pipe(
tap((action: fromActions.Logout) => {
  return this.authService.logout();
}),
map(() => { return {type: 'NO_ACTION'}; })
```

Comment: I tried with return, it's without return, my mistake.

Comment: The `tap` executes the code and returns the passed parameters. You should add a map to return something else then the passed parameter wich is Logout action. I edited my answer to add a code example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is relevant anymore, but I had the same issue and it was because the Logout effect was dispatching an action and got stuck in a loop.
One way to fix this is to configure the Effect to not dispatch any action by adding `{dispatch: false}` inside the @Effect(), so it becomes `@Effect({dispatch: false})`.